# Get php content in apache cordova app

Tags: php, html, cordova, mobile, server-side

I have a dynamic website, which heavily relies on PHP. I want to build a mobile application with it and want to modify my HTML code with PHP or simply just put PHP tags into my HTML document. I would need it to show content from other users (kind of like a blog).

Example:

```
<div id="content">
  <?php echo "<div id='contentfromphp'>some content</div>"; ?>
</div>
```

Is this possible? If not does someone know a way to build a cross-platform app, where I can use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AJAX, PHP won't run in Apache Cordova, from your server you can serve the PHP code and from your app you can load it.

file.php

```
<?php
    //Your PHP Code to serving
?>
```

Script for ajax petition

```
function httpGet(yourUrl){
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", yourUrl,);
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

In your onDocumentReady event

```
httpGet("http://path-to-your-server/php-script.php");
```